# How can I use collect (Collectors.toMap) correctly?

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider:

```
public Map<String, Ethernet> foo() throws SocketException {
    var networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    return Collections.list(networkInterfaces).stream()
        .filter(iFace -> **iFace.getName()**.startsWith("w"))
        .map(this::getEthernet)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(**iFace.getName()????**, Function.identity()));
}

public Ethernet getEthernet(NetworkInterface networkInterface) {
    //return Ethernet
}
```

How can I correctly execute collect to get `iFace.getName()` as the key and the Ethernet object as the value for each stream element?

Comment: Do you mean something like `NetworkInterface::getName`? (In the second case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `getEthernet` in `collect` and not in a map before. Your code can look like this:

```
return Collections.list(networkInterfaces).stream()
        .filter(iFace -> iFace.getName().startsWith("w"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(NetworkInterface::getName, this::getEthernet));
```